# How to implement pagination in RecyclerView which is inside nestedScrollView

Tags: android, pagination, android-recyclerview, nestedscrollview, android-nestedscrollview

I have included `RecyclerView` inside `NestedScrollView` and set

`mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`

Since the scrolling of `RecyclerView` is set to *false*, I will not get the scroll position of `RecyclerView` due to this I will not be able to put pagination in `RecyclerView`.

I have also tried this

```
   mRecylerview.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
        }


        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

            if(dy > 0) {
                totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                if (!isLoading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    // End has been reached
                    // Do something
                    if (mOnLoadMoreListener != null) {
                        mOnLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                        isLoading = true;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

But here **lastVisibleItem** always gives the length of the list to be displayed.

After few digging, I found that when we use `RecylerView` inside `NestedScrollView` all the view gets created at the very beginning so that's the reason why  *lastVisibleItem* always gives the size of the list.

Or if I am wrong please explain, me how `RecyclerView` inside `NestedScrollView` works?.

Is there any workaround so that I can get `RecyclerView` scroll position so that I can make my pagination work?.

It will be a great help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: check my answer here
[stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638779/pagination-not-work-for-the-recyclerview-within-nestedscrollview/52342036#52342036)

Answer (score 6):

Here scroll is NestedScrollView

```
scroll.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(() -> {
                View view = (View) scroll.getChildAt(scroll.getChildCount() - 1);

                Log.d("CategoryNeswList", scroll.getChildCount() + " child");
                int diff = (view.getBottom() - (scroll.getHeight() + scroll
                        .getScrollY()));

                if (diff == 0) {
//                        getPlaylistFromServer("more");
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Load More", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: When it reaches the end of the screen it continuously calls getPlaylistFromServer("more"); method. There should be a way to stop this.