# How to do pagination with NestedScrollView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, pagination, android-nestedscrollview, recyclerview-layout

When I am doing pagination with the nested scroll view it takes too much time, sometimes my app hang? Please tell me the right way to implement pagination with nested scrollview

Comment: you mean pagination in `RecyclerView`?

Comment: My Recyclerview is inside in NestedScrollView So I get action response from Nestedscrollview

Comment: sorry, i have no idea what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I handled all pagination with nestedscrollview action.. because nestedscrollview is my parent view .

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46638845/5308778), I think this is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Your Recyclerview taking so much time because it is inside NestedScrollView and it is getting the full length.  So it is keep calling Next Page automatically till the end (You can check logs).

Answer (score 5):

Add this class in you package

```
    import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class TouchDetectableScrollView extends NestedScrollView {

    OnMyScrollChangeListener myScrollChangeListener;

    public TouchDetectableScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TouchDetectableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TouchDetectableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);

        if (myScrollChangeListener!=null)
        {
            if (t>oldt)
            {
                myScrollChangeListener.onScrollDown();
            }
            else if (t<oldt){
                myScrollChangeListener.onScrollUp();
            }
            View view = (View) getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
            int diff = (view.getBottom()-(getHeight()+getScrollY()));
            if (diff == 0 ) {
                myScrollChangeListener.onBottomReached();
            }
        }
    }

    public OnMyScrollChangeListener getMyScrollChangeListener() {
        return myScrollChangeListener;
    }

    public void setMyScrollChangeListener(OnMyScrollChangeListener myScrollChangeListener) {
        this.myScrollChangeListener = myScrollChangeListener;
    }

    public interface OnMyScrollChangeListener
    {
            public void onScrollUp();
            public void onScrollDown();
            public void onBottomReached();
    }
}
```

Now use `TouchDetectableScrollView` instead `NestedScrollView` in your xml and java code.
and set Listener like this:

```
TouchDetectableScrollView nestedScrollView=findViewById(R.id.nestedScrollView);
        nestedScrollView.setMyScrollChangeListener(new TouchDetectableScrollView.OnMyScrollChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollUp() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollDown() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onBottomReached() {
                // api call for pagination
            }
        });
```

do your pagination task in `onBottomReached` method

Comment: Yes It Works Thanks.. but it sitll takes too much time to load.

Comment: Might be internet issue, which library you are using for API call?

Comment: No this is not internet issue . I am using Retrofil library for making connection

Comment: your Custom nestedScrollview works perfectly fine but not working in ViewPager tab ?

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Set nested scrolling enabled false of recycler view.

recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

**2.** Add scroll listner to nested scrollview.

```
nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                if (isFeedsFetchInProgress)
                    return;
                if(!mOnLastPage) {
                    int visibleItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                    int totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                    int pastVisibleItems = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
                    if (pastVisibleItems + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount) {
                        //End of list
                        mPageToRequest++;
                        loader = LOADER.BOTTOM;
                        hitApiRequest(ApiConstants.REQUEST_TYPE.GET_REFERRAL_LIST);
                    }
                }
//                int topRowVerticalPosition = (recyclerView == null || recyclerView.getChildCount() == 0) ? 0 : recyclerView.getChildAt(0).getTop();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(scrollY <= 0);

            }
        });
```