# Get Scroll in Recyclerview inside Nested Scrollview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have this code addOnScrollListener of recyclerview which is inside a nestedscroll view

```
 mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                mScrollState = newState;
                if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE && adapter.getItemCount() > 0) {
                    mCalculator.onScrollStateIdle();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                mCalculator.onScrolled(mScrollState);
            }
        });
```

i need to get into those methods in addOnScrollListener when i scroll my view.
But unfortunately, while scrolling not entering this methods. can anyone help me
how to get scroll of recyclerview inside the nested scrollview

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46638845/7666442

Comment: @NileshRathod but i need the same above code inorder to maintain some other conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just handled issue by using gesture motion

Answer (score 0):

behalf of new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() try to use NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener. It might be help you to solved your issue

```
nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener((NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener) (v, x, y, x1, y1) -> {
            if(v.getChildAt(v.getChildCount() - 1) != null) {
                if ((x >= (v.getChildAt(v.getChildCount() - 1).getMeasuredHeight() - v.getMeasuredHeight())) &&
                        y > y1) {
                        //code to fetch more data for endless scrolling
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: sorry not helping. the thing is my list consist of text,images and videos three layout are there.when the user scroll and reach video where video is fully visible for user the video should play automatically. For that i need the recyclerview scroll