# NestedScrollView getting stuck with recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I am using `NestedScrollView` and I have 3 recyclerviews . I am parsing json and set data in recyclerview, now the issue is that in my last recyclerview I have set pagination feature, so until data is not fetched for that recyclerview, my whole screen got stuck and freeze. I tried a different solution for that. but it's not working and I found no change in result. can anyone help me with that?

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/reseller_home_title" />

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:id="@+id/bodyScroller"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:background="#f0f0f0"
                android:scrollbars="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/white">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:id="@+id/temp_orange_view"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                            />

                        <com.youth.banner.Banner
                            android:id="@+id/banner"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                            app:indicator_drawable_selected="@drawable/library_module_bg_style_main_radious"
                            app:indicator_height="5dp"
                            app:indicator_width="5dp" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewCategoryData"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                        android:isScrollContainer="false"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/resellerPromotionBannerLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="80dp"
                        android:weightSum="2"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:background="#f0f0f0"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        >
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/iv_top_left_pro"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            />
                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/iv_top_right_pro"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewGroupData"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                        android:isScrollContainer="false"
                        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                        />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewGroupProductData"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="#f0f0f0"
                        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                        android:isScrollContainer="false"
                        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                        />

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#f0f0f0"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        >
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tv_size_text"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="THEY'RE ALL SELLING THIS"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                            android:textSize="16dp" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewHpEntryData"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                        android:isScrollContainer="false"
                        android:background="#f0f0f0"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                        >

                    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_15sdp"
                        android:background="#f0f0f0"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                        >
                        <ProgressBar
                            android:id="@+id/reseller_promotion_view_progress"
                            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:indeterminate="false"
                            android:max="100"
                            android:progress="20"
                            android:maxHeight="3dip"
                            android:minHeight="3dip"
                            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/resellerpromotion_progress" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewProductData"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#f0f0f0"
                        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
                        android:isScrollContainer="false"
                        />


                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp">
                        <ProgressBar
                            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
                    </RelativeLayout>



                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <include layout="@layout/error_layout"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Try this  recyclerview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); @khimji

Comment: @g.brahmaDatta i already tried that approach but it did not work

Comment: Try scrollView instead of nestedScrollView. I did the same concept as you scrollView with three recyclerviews @khimji.

Comment: @g.brahmaDatta nope scrollview also not working

Comment: try to set NestedScrollView height match_parent

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/a/32735182/6021469

Answer (score 0):

run below code for each of your `RecyclerView` within your `NestedScrollView`

```
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recyclerView, false);
```

Comment: for pagination in your last recyclerView i refer you to [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46638779/pagination-not-work-for-the-recyclerview-within-nestedscrollview?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: i guess issue is that, my onbindviewholder method again and again callling during scroll. how to solve that?

Comment: this is not the problem, its `RecyclerView`' adapter's behaviour not an error

Comment: what you are loading in your adapter, is it some kind of heavy data or heavy operations like big images or etc

Comment: check the images size and dimensions that are being load in your adapter if they are big in size or dimension then resize them before loading, (heavy or large images make your UI Very very slow or hang)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190366/discussion-between-khimji-and-muhammad-muzammil-sharif).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it works well,

```
rvCompanies.setHasFixedSize(true);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
rvCompanies.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
rvCompanies.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false); // important
```