# Make LinearLayout and RecyclerView scroll as one container

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

Input data:

1. LinearLayout with a couple of views (further "Info")
2. RecyclerView with pagination

In theory, the objective is easy: make both views scrollable like a single container.
In practice, it is ridiculously complicated.

**Attempt #1: NestedScrollView**

Before I integrated the Paging library, both the Info and the Recycler were inside of a NestedScrollView and it worked as I wanted, except for the performance (sometimes there are ~500 items, and the UI freezes for ~4 seconds).
Now, since RecyclerView is inside the NestedScrollView, my paging doesn't work: it loads all the data at once! I decided to find another way.

**Attempt #2: CoordinatorLayout**

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68195028/17088333) to be a possible solution. And it works perfectly with highly populated RecyclerView. However, when the list is empty, I can scroll all the way down to the blank screen and I won't be able to scroll back up. If I have a few items, I can also scroll halfway to the blank screen. Only a high amount of data works well with this approach. I understand that behavior because I have a scroll flag "exitUntilCollapsed" but is there a workaround for this?

Is there any solution to this problem? Such a simple task requires tons of workarounds (and workarounds for workarounds) to have the info and the recycler to be scrollable as a single container.

Answer (score 0):

there is another solution to solve this problem, use multiple view type to make the linearlayout as a part of recyclerview items. check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914003/recyclerview-and-handling-different-type-of-row-inflation/29362643#29362643) out.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is to put inside your adapter realization different `viewHolder's` and switching between them by different item types (needs to override `getItemViewType`). Here is an article about it, check out: [medium](https://serjantarbuz.medium.com/recyclerview-with-different-items-and-multiple-columns-grid-724618d5d4e4)